# Kernel launched with two-dimension does not work

Tags: cuda

I have a simple kernel to init an array:

```
__global__ void test(int *result) {

    unsigned int gID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int sID = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    result[sID] = sID + gID;
}
```

I want to launch this kernel as if it was a two loop-fashion. My setting are these:

```
int size = 30;
int * result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
int *resultD;
cudaMalloc((void**)&resultD, sizeof(int)*size);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    result[i] = 0;
}

cudaMemcpy(resultD, result, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
dim3 block(100,30);
test<<<1, block>>>(resultD);

cudaMemcpy(result, resultD, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

My results are only 0s (zeros). Can you help me why? Sorry I'm new to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your results are unchanged is that the kernel fails to launch.

Be sure to always check the return error codes from your CUDA api calls from host to catch those type of errors.

In this case you would find an error specifying Launch Failure, and the reason for that is that your block size (30*100=3000) is larger than the maximum size allowed, which is 1024. If you want a kernel with that many threads (which is not unreasonable), you are going to need to divide them into more than one thread block.